# Create Pipelines in Azure DevOps in a big project

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I would like to fully automate my current application deployment process.

I have big project in Azure DevOps. Code was writen on C# for .Net core.
The Solution consists  3 sites and 2 windows service application (build to msi file).
When I was creating Pipelines and choose "Azure Repos Git" and click on my project then in Configure your pipeline choose "ASP.NET CORE".
On "Review your pipeline YAML" I have a problems.

How can I in YAML file point to the site I want to build?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I in YAML file point to the site I want to build?

When you use the `Asp.net Core Yaml` template, it will use the `dotnet build` script to build your project.  You could add the target path to the dotnet build command.

For example:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build **/*.csproj --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

On the other hand, I recommand you to use the task to run the build.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(BuildConfiguration)'
```

You could add the specific path is in the `projects field`.

Here is a doc about [DotNetCoreCLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) and [Task introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).